# Installed Ubuntu on a USB and got some unwanted results

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub2

So, I wanted to install Ubuntu on a simple usb drive but it also installed grub2 on my system (which I didn't want) and now all hells broke loose. Apparently, it set the USB as dev/sda and my default windows as dev/sda2. How do I switch this around so that I can go through the BIOS and select boot from hard drive first (windows but it is held on dev/sda2) or boot from USB? I don't mind the grub but I don't want it to pop up every time I try to boot my laptop when I don't have the usb stick in. Or, is there a way to select dev/sda2 in grub for boot? (I have no knowledge of grub or BASH but know some batch but that probably won't be that helpful.) When the USB is in, it gives me the option to boot from windows from dev/sda2 but without it, it simply boots to grub.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch...sounds like you may have a bigger problem....I been there.....in order to install Linux to the USB you should have used yumi or similar USB installer...hopefully you didn't change much on your main drive but you may now have to....if your system boots normal with the pen drive out great... You should be able to simply pull up your BIOS by pressing ESC,f1-12 or del keys at boot then go to your boot devices and set which drive you want to boot to instead as higher in the sequence. If you are still getting grub problems you may need to shrink your partition and and install Linux as dual boot to the unused area cleared....hopefully you did not wipe anything necessary for Windows to run.

You could also maybe use default Windows recovery software to repair Windows.  The nice thing if you still have Windows on any system get yumi and it will direct you to a number of great software that could help.

Comment: Not quite, Windows Boot is still there. I'm actually using it now. Grub was installed on my main drive so going through the BIOS won't work. When I start up my computer without the USB, a grub command line comes up. When I use the USB, a grub menu comes up giving me a few options including WIndows Boot Manager (/dev/sda2). So, how do I select /dev/sda2 as default or at least select it to boot in grub.

Comment: Try searching grub editor....otherwise use that yumi to get a partitioning tool. And install the Linux as dual boot so all the files are there on the drive itself just a second partition..should allow you to change default OS at boot

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want a dual boot, just a simple USB with Ubuntu installed but grub grubbed it up. I might be able to use a recovery disk to get the mbr back where it should be.

Comment: Then you should still use yumi to install Linux to the USB drive properly... And it can likely help you restore the MBR and everything....trust me its a great tool for these types of problems....